# 2 Popup windows - Android

Tags: android

I have problem, in `activity_main.xml` have two `buttons` (`button1`, `button2`), and have 2 `popup` windows for each button.
But have problem with `mainactivity.java`, I don't know how to implement second window for second `button`.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button btnClosePopup;
    Button btnCreatePopup;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnCreatePopup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btnCreatePopup.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                initiatePopupWindow();
            }
        });

    }

    private PopupWindow pwindo;

    private void initiatePopupWindow() {
        try {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_popup,
                    (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_element));
            pwindo = new PopupWindow(layout, 480, 240, true);
            pwindo.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

            btnClosePopup = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_close_popup);
            btnClosePopup.setOnClickListener(cancel_button_click_listener);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private OnClickListener cancel_button_click_listener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pwindo.dismiss();

        }
    };
}
```

Comment: At a time you can show one PopUp only.

Comment: @Sarvanan, I can initiate a pop up show from already visible pop up, so two pop up's at same time... your understanding is proper explaining was mistake

Comment: Follow the same what you are doing for button 1. when one pop up is opened another pop up from same parent view cannot be opened. one view(parent) can have only one pop up (child view).

Answer (score 0):

This practice isn't recommended, you should deal with one at a time, each solving a problem.

If you really want to do that, you could open a pop up from an already existing. Which again, is not something you should do